# Is it safe to use my mobile headset on my PC?

Tags: audio, headset, security

Is it safe to use my mobile headset on my PC or laptop?

Will it damage my audio chip or corrupt any driver?

In this [site](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-12/16-using_your_mobile_headset_on_a_pc) it says computers 2 TRS connectors, one for speaker and another for  microphone while mobile phone headsets use single 4-conductor TRRS connector. Hence have to use a adapter

Comment: Personally I have used my bluetooth headset for a long time with no issues.

Comment: I dont have a bluetooth headset but I have bluetooth dongle for my PC. So can i connect my PC to mobile via bluetooh and then use my headset (which connected to the mobile).

Comment: Is it okay if I connect my Headphones while my speakers are connected to my PC. and both are turned on ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will it damage my audio chip or corrupt any driver?

No and no. Assuming you're talking about passive headphones + mic with TRRS connector, there's no way it should damage your audio chip, and it is (almost) totally driver-independent.

It's quite likely that you can plug your headset into your PC/Laptop and use the inbuilt headphones without any problem. Many recent 3.5mm TRRS jacks have been constructed to be compatible with stereo headphone (TRS) sockets)

Note that you will not be able to use the Mic in your headset when doing this. To make use of the headphones AND the mic you'll need an adaptor to go from 
TRRS (mic+stereo) --> TRS (stereo) + TRS (mic)

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector):

> A three- or four-conductor version of
>   the 2.5 mm plug is widely used on cell
>   phone handsfree headsets, providing
>   mono (three conductor) or stereo (four
>   conductor) sound and a microphone
>   input. Common stereo headphones with
>   the 2.5 mm plug are often not
>   compatible with this type of socket. A
>   3.5 mm version of this plug is now commonly available on mobile
>   telephones as well. A 3.5 mm
>   stereo-plus-mic jack is available that
>   is compatible with standard 3.5 mm
>   stereo headphones, e.g. Nokia has been
>   widely using TRRS connectors with 3.5
>   mm diameter since 2006. The selected
>   pin assignment, with ground on the
>   sleeve, is as well standardized in
>   OMTP and has been accepted as a
>   national Chinese standard YDT
>   1885-2009.
>
> TRRS plugs do not work properly with a
>   TRS stereo jack if the ground contact
>   in the jack connects to the microphone
>   contact on the plug. It is therefore a
>   good practice to implement new TRS
>   headphone jacks using actually a TRRS
>   mechanical jacks and connecting ground
>   to sleeve as well as the second ring
>   contact. This way such jacks will
>   provide better compatibility with
>   different TRRS cell phone headsets.

Comment: Okay so as long as I have a 3.5 mm headset I  should have no worries, right?

Comment: Typically, TRS,TRRS pins are arranged in such a way that You have Left, Right, Ground for stereo audio headphones without a microphone,  and Left, Right, Ground, Mic for stereo headphones that have a microphone. This means that the Mic position being last on the jack means that it will never activate when a headset is plugged in. In such a case, you'd have a splitter which'd convert from TRRS input to two TRS outputs, one for headphones and one for Mic.

Refer http://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/ for a diagram showing this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use it...there are a variety of ways to connect...

If you're worried, create a *[System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-System-Restore)* point and try it.  If you experience any effects that you don't like, just roll back to your restore point.

Comment: Why would the computer need bluetooth?

Comment: @AndreajaKo: I'm not well educated in this area...My answer was more of a guess...I suppose it could work like a wireless mouse does...

Comment: In the past one of motherboard's audio chip went damaged after I connected a cheap headphone. So I am a little afraid to connect it.

Comment: @subanki: that's understandable.

Comment: This is very low-level, physical-only connection that will have no bearing on software. Creating a system restore point is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

For proper use of a "Headset" a stereo headphone microphone combo with the TRRS 4 conductor 3.5mm jack plug I would suggest a GE 26694 single trrs to dual trrs Smartphone-to-PC adapter or equivalent; as you will be able to use BOTH the microphone and the stereo headphone capabilities of said headset.

There are some newer computers that do not need a(n) adapter for full functionality, for instance a lot of the new macs and the HP DM1Z. --1/21/2012

There are also PC headset dual trs to single trrs converters so pc headsets can be used with smartphones.